# React-native Error while generating an upload bundle for iOS - main.jsbundle

Tags: ios, react-native

I need to generate the upload bundle for ios. I am using `npm run ios -- --mode=Release` as instructed.

All is fine, until the tools tries to generate / write main.jsbundle in the DerivedData directory.

The exact error message is `error EPERM: operation not permitted, open <full absolute path>`

Any suggestions?

I tried to delete the whole DerivedData directory. Same result

I also tried to touch, with success, the bundle file (using a copy paste of the full path from the error message, just to avoid typos....). So basic permission issues appear to not be it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after trying to directly generate the bundle in Xcode I found that I was experiencing the same issue. Made it easier to find the answer....

The solution was in XCode, under Build Option. Simply turn Off / Disable (answer "No")

`User Script Sandboxing`